# Major museum for traditional arts in China akin to France's Louvre

Tags: china, taiwan, museums

Is there a major, representative (perhaps national) museum devoted to traditional Chinese arts in Beijing or perhaps in another of the country's large cities? I am thinking of something akin to France's Louvre plus its Musée d'Orsay.

Does such a place exist or would one better look at museums in Taiwan (or perhaps the MET in New York City)?

Comment: Pretty sure you're looking for the [National Museum of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Museum_of_China), but since I've never been there I'm posting this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Yes!  The IFC luxury consumer mall in HK!  It's under the Four Seasons!  :-)

Comment: China is the epitome of a hyper-rich, ultra-rich, mega-rich, nouveau riche nation.  (All of which is a good thing.)  The Musée d'Orsay is the antithesis of those qualities.  (The Louvre (and the new Louvre Abu Dhabi Branch!) is a crass tourist attraction!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The collection at the [National Palace Museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Palace_Museum) on Taiwan is quite extensive. The KMT removed most of those items in their retreat to Taiwan in 1949, and they tend to represent the best of the best.

The Museum is in central Taipei with a southern branch. Currently, [general adult entry](https://www.npm.gov.tw/en/Article.aspx?sNo=02007001) costs NT350 or about USD $11.50.

The Palace Museum (which originally held many of those objects) in Beijing costs CNY 60 for summmer entry or about $9 USD. Both are interesting and worth a visit.

Comment: +1, this is the right answer.  It's called the Palace Museum because it contains everything the emperors of China collected over the centuries, and spirited out of the Forbidden City before the Communists took over.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of putting in the first answer, you should surely rock on over to the

[Shanghai Museum](https://travel.usnews.com/Shanghai_China/Things_To_Do/Shanghai_Museum_62573/)

[image]

In China, Beijing is the statist, goverment city, and Shanghai is the groovy commercial city.  (A bit like, say, Washington V. Los Angeles, or Canberra V. Melbourne, or Brussels V. Berlin.)

@MichaelSeifert has already mentioned the big one in Beijing, but I recommend the Shanghai Museum.

**China's "museum boom" of the last decade...**

China, as the ultimate nouveau riche entity on the planet, has gone through it's "[museum boom](https://www.economist.com/special-report/2014/01/06/mad-about-museums)" (you can read [endless](https://www.dezeen.com/2015/12/11/new-chinese-museums-construction-boom-opening-money-cant-buy-culture-china/) ... [sarcastic](https://www.arch.columbia.edu/events/291-the-museum-boom-in-china-innovations-and-global-aspirations) ... [articles](http://bop.co.uk/articles/Understanding-Chinas-Museum-Boom) on this by Westerners who don't like having it pointed out that museums are pretentious), so, your desire for cultural artifacts will be well catered-for in all major cities.

Simply click to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanghai_Museum#Galleries) to get an idea of the absurdly large collection of Culture on hand at the Shanghai mega-Museum. It's the Alibaba.com of culture.

Comment: Why the downvotes?